# Как задать два сайта на одном серве Апач?

Tags: apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/home/
        ServerName 10.10.10.10 //test
        ServerAlias edu2.bi.group edu2.bi-group.org

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/site/
        ServerName  edu3.bi-group.org
        ServerAlias edu3.bi-group.org edu3.bi.group
</VirtualHost>
```

Как правильно тут записать или писать надо в разных файлах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала создаёте каталоги и назначаете права.

Далее создаёте конфигурационные файлы для каждого хоста.

1й хост

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

2й хост

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example2.com
    ServerAlias www.example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example2.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

После этого можно включать хосты в консоли.

```
sudo a2ensite config1.conf
sudo a2ensite config2.conf
```

Вместо config1 и config2 указываете реальные имена файлов конфигурации.

Ещё по созданию виртуальных хостов есть хорошая инструкция [здесь](https://www.8host.com/blog/nastrojka-virtualnyx-xostov-apache-v-ubuntu-16-04/).